# How to attach html response (got from ajax request )with div tag in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

**Below is the code snippet which is hitting the url on server and getting the html response.I can see
the response inside firefox debugger but it does not display in div tag.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: '',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        //in firefox debugger i can see complete html response inside data 
        $('#displayContent').html(data); // but here, it does not  
        // append the html inside div displayContent. Instead it makes 
        // the current page blank
    }
});​
```

**I don't get what mistake I'm making here** Can I not directly assign the ajax html response to an selector(div tag in my case) with `$('#displayContent').html(data)`?

Comment: Do you have several elements with id of `displayContent`? or is `displayContent` the id of your markup wrapper? note that html method replaces the content, it doesn't append the data.

Comment: Change div's class to displayContent and do  $('.displayContent').html(data); and tell us if that did the trick.

Comment: @undefined only single displayContent

Comment: @ user1071979 trick did not work

Comment: @MSach Can you post the markup?

Comment: hard code `$('#displaycontent').html('<div>test</div>')` and see if that works.  If it does, then it could just mean the `data` coming back is not proper html.  See if it shows up when you inspect the element.

Comment: $('#displaycontent').html('<div>test</div>') works.Regarding the statement " If it does, then it could just mean the data coming back is not proper html. See if it shows up when you inspec" same jsp is working at another location. So does not look like issue related to proper html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using html() method use append i.e.

```
$('#displayContent').append(data);
```

Or if you want to assign whole content direct to your element use load method

```
$(function(){
   $('#displayContent').load(url);
});
```

Comment: $('#displayContent').append(data); also making the current page blank

Comment: @MSach try the second approach remove your existing stuff and use it.

Comment: okay i guess there is some problem in the data which your are getting from url, might be incomplete tags or some kind of css classes that hides your current page elements.

Comment: here what is url and where can I find out?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a form tag on your page, and you're trying to submit it asynchronously with jQuery, your function will need to return `false`, to prevent the browser from handling the form.

Example:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  $.ajax(...);
  return false;
});
```